# How to  count number of rows and make it as a condition when VBA inserts rows in between?

Tags: vba, excel

I Need to use a loop in my code and at a certain condition I will insert row.

```
Rowz = activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
for j=3 to Rowz ' say number of rowz=1000
```

But as rows are inserted in between So the number of rows are increased. Say for example at the 200th row I insert 4 rows and 500th row I insert 10 rows So the number is increased to more than 1000 now so the loop tests till 1000 ignoring the remaining rows which are pushed down due to inserting. But I need to perform that loop till the last row even rows are inserted in between

I thought to use these

```
  for j=3 to activesheet.cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
```

But the value is not updating  i Guess its just checking upto 1000 only its not updating the number of rows value in the to condtion.

How do I count number of rows and keep it in a condition if rows are created in between?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you try looping backwards ? `for j = rowZ to 3 step -1`.
Might that solve your problem ?

---

Edit: option 2, you could define a name for the cell after the last one, and refer that Named Range: `Range("myLastCell")`. It will adjust every time you insert rows....

Comment: Another way is to do that can also be done by going thru the loop in the straight direction (from 3 to rowZ) but whenever a row is inserted, then the loop controller variable (j) should be decreased every time an insert is executed.

Comment: @Ahmad: there are probably plenty of ways...but I favor a simple and efficient one :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might try to loop through a range:

```
Sub LoopRange()
   Dim cell As Range, Rowz as Long
   Rowz = Activesheet.Cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
   For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Rowz)
    'do things
   Next Bcell
End Sub
```

**Warning:** the vba will parse the whole range, *including* the inserted rows, so if you insert a row on every loop, your procedure will loop indefinitely (note, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to stop the execution of your code if it happens)